# Jquery call trigger method when other trigger method is finished

Tags: jquery

In my project I'm using three chained selects.

html

```
<select name="id_foo">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
<select name="id_bar">
</select>
<select name="id_doe">
</select> 
<br>
<input type="button" id="auto" value"auto complete">
```

js

```
var $sel_foo = $('select[name="id_foo"]');
var $sel_bar = $('select[name="id_bar"]');
var $sel_doe = $('select[name="id_doe"]');


/** Chained Select (id_foo) */
$sel_foo.on('change', function() {
    var id_foo = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : ajax.php,
        data    : { id_foo: id_foo },
        success : function(data) {
            $sel_bar.html(data);
        }
    });
});

/** Chained Select (id_bar) */
$sel_bar.on('change', function() {
    var id_bar = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : ajax.php,
        data    : { id_bar: id_bar },
        success : function(data) {
            $sel_doe.html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

For simulte the human action I use the trigger method.
Unfortunately I had to enter a timeout (2 sec) between triggers methods
otherwise select were called before they were loaded entirely (ajax response)

```
$('#auto').on('click', function(){
   $sel_foo.trigger("change");
   setTimeout( function() { $sel_bar.trigger("change"); }, 2000);
});
```

I would try to do it cleaner, running the next trigger only when the called function from the previous trigger is finished. How could I do this? thank you

EDIT

I tried this, but with no success.

```
 $.when($sel_foo.trigger("change"))
  .then($sel_bar.trigger("change"));
```

Comment: Instead of `$sel_bar.prop.html(data);` it should be `$sel_bar.html(data);`. Now why don't you call `$sel_bar.trigger("change");` from $sel_foo change event ajax request success callback?  Be aware, i'm not sure to understand your logic there. Why do you need to trigger event?

Comment: @Wolff - I correct the code. I use the trigger for autoload data for edit page

Comment: But doesn't it works as you want it: `$sel_bar.html(data).trigger('change');`?

Comment: @Wolff - I edited my code, perhaps it is more clear what I'm trying to do

Comment: You could try with [this library](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained/demo.html) to do that. See the last example about **Multiple chained remote**.

Comment: @newpatriks - Thank you but I know that library and do not want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following logic:

```
$sel_foo.on('change', function(e) {
    var id_foo = this.value,
        self = this; // keep ref on `this`
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "/echo/html",
        data    : { id_foo: id_foo },
        success : function(data) {
            $sel_bar.html(data);
            if(e.isTrigger) $sel_bar.trigger('change');
        }
    });
});

$('#auto').on('click', function(){
   $sel_foo.trigger("change"); // on click only trigger first SELECT change event
});
```

Comment: it works! although I thought it was easier to do. Honestly I have to study because I did not understand what you did.. Thanks

Comment: @PaoloRossi Indeed, if i understand it, you could just use following updated answer, checking if onchange event has been triggered or not

Comment: this is much more clean/simple and that's what I was looking for ! thank you!